# How to Setup Ethereum Based Website

Tags: contract-development, web3js, contract-deployment, aws

I have a Wordpress website on one server. And on AWS (another server) I have block chain installed.
Now I want to show the Block chain data (Smart Contarct Informationor Transactions) into my wordpress website. I know I can use web3js for the same. But do I need to install something on my wordpress server to run Web3js Commands?

Regards
AKM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just have to write the JS code to interact with Web3js. It can be server-side (Node.js), as well as client-side. Check out [the web3 doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) for configuration instructions and some basic usage examples.

If you just want to display some ordinary stuff from your blockchain, you may go client-side way and write a couple of lines to fetch information.

If you are looking for more complex things, you just have to develop a Node.js app (API) which will be the layer between your Blockchain and your WP website.

Comment: Thanks @someart  for the details. Can't I use Web3JS directly with my Wordpress Pages?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by WordPress pages. You just have to include that .js file with all code you need to your page (.html/.php). As far as I know, there is no obvious plugin for WP to interact with web3. So you have to write such functionality manually.

Comment: Yes I do agree with your comments. So If I need to write web3js code into my .html or .php files of Worspress, in that case do I need to install web3JS on the server where wordpress is installed ?

Comment: You will have to write your code in .js file which should be included to your .php/.html page. And web3 should be a part of .js file